# H2O Import files via REST API from local server fails

Tags: h2o

I am trying to use h2o REST API to import CSV files that I have on my local server.

**Command:**

> curl -v -X GET
>   'http://127.0.0.1:54321/3/ImportFiles?path=http://127.0.0.1:8083/datasets/tables/csv/RDsTWgcvAjHeWJFnbhCKTCE5rn6aLCjJ.csv'

**Result in following log:**

> Trying 127.0.0.1... Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 54321 (#0)
>   GET
>   /3/ImportFiles?path=http://127.0.0.1:8083/datasets/tables/csv/RDsTWgcvAjHeWJFnbhCKTCE5rn6aLCjJ.csv HTTP/1.1 Host: 127.0.0.1:54321 User-Agent: curl/7.47.0 Accept: */*
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK X-h2o-build-project-version: 3.16.0.2
>   X-h2o-rest-api-version-max: 3 X-h2o-cluster-id: 1512722051559
>   X-h2o-cluster-good: true X-h2o-context-path: / Content-Type:
>   application/json Content-Length: 349 Server: Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)
>   Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
>   {"__meta":{"schema_version":3,"schema_name":"ImportFilesV3","schema_type":"ImportFiles"},"_exclude_fields":"","path":"http://127.0.0.1:8083/datasets/tables/csv/RDsTWgcvAjHeWJFnbhCKTCE5rn6aLCjJ.csv","pattern":null,"files":[],"destination_frames":[],"fails":["http://127.0.0.1:8083/datasets/tables/csv/RDsTWgcvAjHeWJFnbhCKTCE5rn6aLCjJ.csv"],"dels":[]}

**H2O log on TRACE level shows only:**

> 12-08 15:41:59.951 10.8.128.101:54321    36013  #4756-331 INFO: GET
>   /3/ImportFiles, parms:
>   {path=http://127.0.0.1:8083/datasets/tables/csv/RDsTWgcvAjHeWJFnbhCKTCE5rn6aLCjJ.csv}

Is there any way to debug while importing fails? h2o does not asking local server at all.

**Commands from other servers work well:**

> curl -v -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:54321/3/ImportFiles?path=http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/flow_examples/arrhythmia.csv.gz"
>   curl -v -X GET "https://raw.github.com/h2oai/h2o/master/smalldata/logreg/prostate.csv"

Answer (score 1):

In general, trying to interact directly with the H2O REST API isn't easy.  The vast majority of people use a pre-made API client like Python or R.

But if you really want to do this, I would debug it by comparing with something that's working.  Like the R client for H2O.

Write an R program that does this:

```
h2o.init()
h2o.startLogging()
h2o.importFile("/path/to/data.csv")
```

The startLogging() call will produce a detailed log file with all the REST API requests and responses.  Look at that and try to mimic it.

You can also refer to the autogenerated REST API documentation (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/rest-api-reference.html), but I would caution that if you tried to write a working client just based on the docs it would be hard.

Looking at a logged conversation from an already working client is by far your best bet.

Comment: This is not answer to my question. I already provided log of HTTP requests and responses from all sides. Question is: why does H2O fail importing and does not report anything about why is this happened without any calls to my local server.

Comment: I tried your R code and got the same log as posted before.

Comment: If you think you got the same log as before, you're looking at the wrong thing.  I suggest trying again.  The new log is on the client side, not the server side.

Answer (score 0):

> library(h2o)
>
> h2o.init() 
>   h2o.startLogging()
>   h2o.importFile("http://localhost:8082/datasets/tables/csv/vPrzC5TOQr6JTvnAYrU5AKyz8SP4ao8p.csv")
>
> ---
>
> Time:     2017-12-11 11:55:09.237
>
> GET       http://localhost:54321/3/Cloud?skip_ticks=true postBody:
>
> curlError:         FALSE curlErrorMessage:   httpStatusCode:    200
>   httpStatusMessage: OK millis:            7
>
> {"__meta":{"schema_version":3,"schema_name":"CloudV3","schema_type":"Iced"},"_exclude_fields":"","skip_ticks":true,"version":"3.16.0.2","branch_name":"rel-wheeler","build_number":"2","build_age":"10 days","build_too_old":false,"node_idx":0,"cloud_name":"H2O_started_from_R_vasiliy_gey658","cloud_size":1,"cloud_uptime_millis":306486,"cloud_healthy":true,"bad_nodes":0,"consensus":true,"locked":true,"is_client":false,"nodes":[{"__meta":{"schema_version":3,"schema_name":"NodeV3","schema_type":"Iced"},"h2o":"localhost/127.0.0.1:54321","ip_port":"127.0.0.1:54321","healthy":true,"last_ping":1512982506643,"pid":97891,"num_cpus":4,"cpus_allowed":4,"nthreads":4,"sys_load":2.0917969,"my_cpu_pct":-1,"sys_cpu_pct":-1,"mem_value_size":17408,"pojo_mem":12224512,"free_mem":1896688640,"max_mem":1908930560,"swap_mem":0,"num_keys":56,"free_disk":0,"max_disk":0,"rpcs_active":0,"fjthrds":[-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"fjqueue":[-1,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"tcps_active":0,"open_fds":-1,"gflops":4.598999977111816,"mem_bw":6.423728128E9}],"internal_security_enabled":false}
>
> ---
>
> Time:     2017-12-11 11:55:09.251
>
> GET
>   http://localhost:54321/3/ImportFiles?path=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8082%2Fdatasets%2Ftables%2Fcsv%2FvPrzC5TOQr6JTvnAYrU5AKyz8SP4ao8p.csv&pattern=
>   postBody:
>
> curlError:         FALSE curlErrorMessage:   httpStatusCode:    200
>   httpStatusMessage: OK millis:            6
>
> {"__meta":{"schema_version":3,"schema_name":"ImportFilesV3","schema_type":"ImportFiles"},"_exclude_fields":"","path":"http://localhost:8082/datasets/tables/csv/vPrzC5TOQr6JTvnAYrU5AKyz8SP4ao8p.csv","pattern":"","files":[],"destination_frames":[],"fails":["http://localhost:8082/datasets/tables/csv/vPrzC5TOQr6JTvnAYrU5AKyz8SP4ao8p.csv"],"dels":[]}

Answer (score 0):

This is my import information.
[image]